# gdb prints weird completions

Tags: autocomplete, gdb

For instance when I go to tab complete after file.c for matching .cpp, I get things like the following. I have built with -g -ggdb -03

```
fileName.calloc     fileName.calloc@got.plt
fileName.calloc@plt     fileName.ceil
fileName.ceil@got.plt   fileName.ceil@plt
fileName.clock_gettime  fileName.clock_gettime@got.plt
fileName.clock_gettime@plt  fileName.close
fileName.close@got.plt  fileName.close@plt
fileName.coeff_ab(double*, double*, double, double, double, double, double)
fileName.coerceAngle0to2PI(double*)     fileName.coerceAngle0to2PI(float*)
...
```

[image]

Comment: So, what's the actual problem here?

Comment: its that there's not supposed to be anything that could possibly complete except for the header and source file.  I type ```rmemainwindow.``` and gdb completion blows up with all this.  It causes random slowdowns throughout the completion phases because suddenly there's 100's of noise candidates for various stages of the completion.  I'm wondering if this is something that I can fix through compiling my code differently or changeing gdb settings, or if its a bug of some kind

Comment: Since we don't see the source code, it's impossible to say if these completions make any sense or not.

Comment: the completions don't make any sense for the prefix in question, which is a filename.  the only things possible to complete from the rmeMainWindow is the source file or header file itself. so the completion choices should be rmeMainWindow.cpp or rmeMainWindow.h